# What does נמר in Tanach mean

Tags: words, talmud-gemara, hebrew, tanach, animals

What does נמר quoted in this Passuk mean:

> ירמיהו יג, כג: היהפוך כושי עורו ו**נמר** חברבורותיו

I see it translated as a **leopard**
e.g. in [mishna avot 5.20](http://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.5.20?lang=en) and in
"[What's the point of Jeremiah 13:18–27?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43892/5120)"

Someone told me it is incorrect and it means **tiger**.

Ifs he is correct what is the source?

Alternatively could there be another explanation?

Comment: The shape of the spots are not congruent with Tiger but more vith panther menumar in several mishna.  Azut also suggested that  namer is panther=leopard

Comment: @kouty Panthera

Includes in it leopard and tiger

Comment: http://www.zootorah.com/assets/media/LeopardLayout.pdf has everything you need.

Comment: @hazoriz yes in terminology panthera includes also panthera Leo  but in non latin language panther is leopard and perhaps particularly black panther

Comment: @kouty but plack panther has not spots?

Comment: @kouty it looks like tigers did not live near Israel

Comment: As for עז כנמר, I think a tiger fits much better than a leopard.

Answer (score 2):

[Sukkah 36a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.36a.5) refers to a spotted etrog as "menumar", meaning spotted. That would indicate that a Nemer is probably a leopard, and that the popular translation is indeed spot-on.

Comment: Cheetahs have spots too.

Comment: @DoubleAA you're right, I just meant as opposed to a tiger

Comment: You are indeed “spot-on.” I edited in the daf for you.

Answer (score 2):

Rav Ovadia Bar Tenura Pirkei Avot, 5,20 explains that a נמר is a cross breed between a wild boar and a Lioness.

> עז כנמר - הנמר הזה נולד מן חזיר היער והלביאה, כי בעת יחם האריות הלביאה מכנסת ראשה בסבכי היער ונוהמת ותובעת את הזכר, והחזיר שומע קולה ורובעה, ונמר יוצא מבין שניהן.

Comment: Probably how they understood leopards in those days.