# Prophecy about the destruction of the second temple?

Tags: tanach, churban-destruction, prophecies, rome

Are there any prophecies about the destruction of the second temple?

Comment: What's the connection between the two questions?

Comment: Im asking if there’s any prophecy concerning the destruction of the second temple

Comment: If you use the following search, you will get some answers in various statements in gemara, midrash and commentaries: https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=על%20חרבן%20בית%20שני&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=chronological&svar=1&ssort=relevance

Comment: @RaulValdezJr. I took out the Romans part as I think it is garnering close votes. Feel free to revert

Comment: Related: "[Did foreknowledge stop people?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87702/1368)"

Answer (score 1):

[Daniel 9](https://www.sefaria.org/Daniel.9.24?lang=bi) describes a prophecy of 70 sevens. This is a period of 490 years. The first 70 years of this prophecy are the 70 years of exile starting after the destruction of the First Temple by the Bavlim.

The remaining 420 years are from the building of the Second Temple until its destruction by the Romans 420 years later.